# how to return error message if reactive variable calculation failed in Shiny?

Tags: r, validation, shiny

I creating a shiny app to do some statistics.
I want the shiny app to return an error message if any calculation that I have in a reactive variable failed. Is that possible?

My reactive variables use some imported .csv files and I currently use req() expressions inside my reactive variable to stop the calculation until the file is uploaded. But if by any chance the reactive variable can not be calculated because the imported csv file does not contain what its needed, or have more columns or the calculation gave an invite various or something else, I want to return an error message saying "Please check your data".

Here is what Ive been using:

```
 variables=reactive({
          req(input$firstfile)
          req(input$secondfile)
          req(input$inputtime)
          req(input$inputreplicate)
          
    })
```

Right now, if I use a mock csv file with some errors in it, Shiny just stops running my app and I get the error in R Studio.
I don't really want to use validate() or need() because the csv files are pretty big and I would have to specify 20-30 conditions for each csv file.

Any ideas?

Comment: More details and clarity are needed. Why don't you implement a check of your data?

Comment: I've tried to use validate(), need() or req() but I don't like those approaches. The imported csv files are extensive and I don't want to include 20 conditions in my validate() expression. Is there a way to check if the reactive variable was calculated successfully? and if not to return an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a package perfect for this. It's called shinydisconect.
I used a función that returns an error message no matter what happens in the calculations:

```
disconnectMessage(
  text = "Something went wrong. Please refresh the page and check your input data",
  refresh = "Refresh",
  background = "#FFFFFF",
  colour = "#000000",
  refreshColour = "#0461B3",
  overlayColour = "#000000",
  overlayOpacity = 0.75,
  width = 450,
  top = "center",
  size = 22,
  css = ""
)
```